# Transpose data into dictionary of int and list

Tags: json, linq, dictionary

I have data in my database stored as

ID        DateID     Country        NoOfPeople

2    20130301   Indonesia   2

3    20130301   Malaysia    128

4    20130301   United Kingdom  2

6    20130302   Australia   1

24   20130303   Australia   2

25   20130303   Bhutan  11

26   20130303   Canada  1

27   20130303   Fiji    1

28   20130303   Finland 1

52   20130304   Australia   2

53   20130304   Bhutan  10

54   20130304   Canada  1

55   20130304   Fiji    1

I wish to transpose this data into a dictionary where the DateID is the key and the value is a list of country objects with properties for the country and noOfPeople

i.e. `Dictionary<int, List<Country>>`

I return the data to my application using LINQ and then traverse the results creating a list of the countries and numbers for each unique date id. This works but I’m looking for a more elegant and efficient solution.

My ultimate goal is to outpout JSON in the format

```
PeopleByCountry":{

"20130301":

[

{"country":"Indonesia"," noOfPeople ":2},
{"country":"Malaysia"," noOfPeople ":128},
{"country":"United Kingdom"," noOfPeople ":2}
],

"20130302":
[
{"country":"Indonesia","noOfPeople":1},
{"country":"Australia"," noOfPeople ":1}
]
}
```

Which I’m doing with NewtonSoft.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `IEnumerable<Row>`, say `rows`, for some class `Row` that has the properties on each row of you data, then you can create the desired structure with the Linq query:

```
rows.ToLookup(r => r.DateID).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Then using any standard JSON serializer should get you the desired format.  Read more about `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx).